# Heroku is installing the wrong JDK for my App and failing to deploy it

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my spring boot app (JDK 15.0.1) on heroku through github, but I get the error message

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project conference-demo: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 15 -> [Help 1]
```

I already added a file called system.properties to my application resources folder, with the following content

```
java.runtime.version =15
```

And here's the pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myPackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>conference-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myApp</name>
    <description>Something</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

But heroku still seems to be trying to deploy with Java 1.8. The first message the build log shows is

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack

-----> Java app detected

-----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Can you check what's the JAVA_HOME set in your mvn.bat

Comment: Where is the mvn.bat stored by default?

Comment: Check-in Maven installation folder-->bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `pom.xml` add your own context as below. Paste this code in `effective POM` before the root element ends, after declaring dependencies, and adjust the version as per your requirement.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Adding this worked. It wasn't working because I had it set to 15.

However, doesn't this mean that it rolled back to java 1.8?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while deploying on Heroku, I solved it by creating a **system.properties** file in the root folder of your project, with the below content:

`java.runtime.version=15`

The version should be same as the java version in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

for ***Gradle*** based projects:
here are few steps:

1. pres `ctrl+alt+s` and verify your project sdk version
2. goto root of your project where build.gradle and setting.gradle files are present
3. here create a new file name system.properties(this file is dettected for deploying Heroku apps to override default propeties)
4. in this newly created file write this piece of line `java.runtime.version=17.0.5` or what  ever jdk version you want to deploy with..
5. update the repo with this file using `add.`' '`commit`' and `git push heroku master`
   thats all :)